# Global reach of char *argv[ ] and int argc C++

Tags: c++, c, variables, program-entry-point

I've got the main function: **main(int argc, char *argv[])**. I want to use these variables: **argc,argv** in   other function:

```
int function()

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 ...
 function();
 ...
 return 0;
}

int function()
 {
 int b=argc;
 return 0;
 }
```

but the compilator give error, that **argv** is undeclared. How can I use these variables in other functions?

Comment: I think you mean "... that argc is undeclared", right?

Comment: Simply pass them as arguments when you call it. They're just like any other function arguments.

Comment: If so, its because you didnt pass it as argument to function

Comment: Please, please, stop coding, get a good C book or tutorial and study it. That will save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

argc and argv are local variables of main. You can pass them to other functions as arguments. For example

```
int function( int );

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 ...
 function( argc );
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I want use char *argv[] as an argument of function, compilator show error that there should be something before bracket ] I use Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 6):

Pass them as arguments to your functions.

```
int function(int argc)
{
   int b = argc;
   return 0;
}
```

and call

```
function(argc);
```

in  `main`

Answer (score 5):

As you tagged this as `C++` too, you can do the following trick:

```
int argc;
char **argv;

void foo() {
    printf("argc: %d\n", argc);
    for (int i=0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("%s \n", argv[i]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ::argc = argc;
    ::argv = argv;
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

declare function as

```
int function (int argc) {
    int b = argc;
    ....
}
```

call function in main like

```
function(argc);
```

OR

use a static variable to store your argc and argv, but this is not recommanded

before you main

```
int g_argc;
char* g_argv[];
```

in your main function

```
g_argc = argc;
g_argv = argv;
function();
```

int your function just use g_argc directly

Comment: Why it say: error: 'g_argv' has an incomplete type?

Comment: @appqui-platform: Because, outside of a function parameter list, the array is not equivalent and you must declare `char **g_argv;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to make two global variables to hold the same values as argc and *argv